Weird behaviour of CUDA recursion
In the following minimal reproducible example, when the recursion in device_func is active, the __synchthreads() barrier is ignored, and when debugged, breakpoint 2 occurs before breakpoint 1. If the recursion is removed, it works as expected. How could this be? The code is compiled with nvcc -arch=sm_61 -G -g example.cu for an NVIDIA Quadro P600, using CUDA Toolkit 12.5.
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

__device__ void device_func(uint32_t *octants, size_t const level)
{
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        octants[0] = 0; //! breakpoint 1
    }
    __syncthreads();
    printf("first octant: %d\n", octants[0]); //! breakpoint 2
    //! if used, breakpoint 2 occurs before breakpoint 1
    if (level < 2)
    {
        device_func(octants, level + 1);
    };
}

__global__ void kernel()
{
    __shared__ uint32_t octants[9];

    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        octants[0] = 99999;
    }

    __syncthreads();
    device_func(octants, 0);
    return;
}

void checkCudaError(cudaError_t err, const char *msg)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUDA error at %s: %s\n", msg, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main()
{
    kernel<<<1, 32>>>();

    // Check for kernel launch errors
    checkCudaError(cudaGetLastError(), "Kernel launch");

    // Wait for the kernel to finish executing
    checkCudaError(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), "Kernel execution");

    return 0;
}

Here is the debug session:
$ nvcc -o example -arch=sm_61 -G -g example.cu 
ptxas warning : Stack size for entry function '_Z6kernelv' cannot be statically determined
$ cuda-gdb ./example
NVIDIA (R) cuda-gdb 12.5
Portions Copyright (C) 2007-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Based on GNU gdb 13.2
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This CUDA-GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/developer-tools/cuda-developer-tools/cuda-gdb>.
Find the CUDA-GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/index.html>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./example...
(cuda-gdb) b 11
Breakpoint 1 at 0xabfc: file /home/marco/phase_2_barnes_hut/example.cu, line 20.
(cuda-gdb) b 14
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0xabfc.
Breakpoint 2 at 0xabfc: file /home/marco/phase_2_barnes_hut/example.cu, line 20.
(cuda-gdb) r
Starting program: /home/marco/phase_2_barnes_hut/example 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff6dff000 (LWP 1519)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5b21000 (LWP 1520)]
[Detaching after fork from child process 1521]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5320000 (LWP 1529)]
[Thread 0x7ffff5320000 (LWP 1529) exited]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5320000 (LWP 1530)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe1fff000 (LWP 1532)]
[Switching focus to CUDA kernel 0, grid 1, block (0,0,0), thread (1,0,0), device 0, sm 0, warp 0, lane 1]

CUDA thread hit Breakpoint 2, device_func (octants=0x7fffe5000000, level=0) at example.cu:14
14          printf("first octant: %d\n", octants[0]); //! breakpoint 2
(cuda-gdb)


I didn't seem to have any trouble with it.  See here. (Linux, L4 GPU, CUDA 12.2). How are you deciding that the __syncthreads() is ignored?  Is that based on the breakpoints, or is there some other observation you haven't mentioned?

Perhaps you might want to show your full debug session, just as I have shown it in my example.

Note that there is a potential read-after-write hazard between different recursion levels. Suppose that "breakpoint 1line readsoctans[0] = levelthen thread from warp 1 may writefirst octant: 0orfirst octant: 1`, depending if warp/thread 0 reached the assignment inside the recursion or not before warp 1 reached printf. This may be related as breakpoint 2 of warp 1 can hit before or after breakpoint 1 of inner recursion call of warp 0.

"This may be related as breakpoint 2 of warp 1 can hit before or after breakpoint 1 of inner recursion call of warp 0. " I don't agree.   Regarding the actual code provided, first of all, there is only one warp. But even if there were multiple warps, breakpoint 1 should be hit before any thread or warp can proceed into the recursive call.  That is guaranteed by the __syncthreads() statement.  Likewise, the same __syncthreads() prevents any thread in any warp from hitting the line commented with breakpoint 2 before one thread has hit the line commented with breakpoint 1.

What can happen and often happens to me, is that when stepping through code (without breakpoints) the debugger will make a thread active (say T1) and then skip over code that only applies to T0. Also on Visual studio the debugger will disable breakpoints on repeated runs, making it seem as if the breakpoint was skipped, but in fact the debugger disabled it for no discernible reason. In VS you have to double-check that all breakpoints are enabled. This is most easily done by setting enable break on launch to true and then disabling and reenabling all breakpoints at that first break.

Hi everyone, thanks for the quick replies! I have added the full debug session, which is different to yours @RobertCrovella.

my suggestion is to file a bug.

After filing a bug, I was told that this is expected for a Pascal GPU, since divergent threads are not supported. More info here.

I am aware of divergent threads, but even then I don't see how breakpoint 2 can be hit first?

In the link, if  you scroll down a bit, it states: "Although __syncthreads() has been consistently documented as synchronizing all threads in the thread block, Pascal and prior architectures could only enforce synchronization at the warp level. In certain cases, this allowed a barrier to succeed without being executed by every thread as long as at least some thread in every warp reached the barrier."

As I am reading it, this means, that if at least one thread reached the barrier, the system assumed that all threads reached it. In a non-divergent code (__syncthreads not appearing under some divergent if, or some threads exiting/returning early) this should not be a problem. I don't see divergence in your code, unless the threadIdx.x == 0 causes some lasting effects beyond the branch. If that is the case, they shot themselves in the foot. How could your code even be fixed to behave correctly!?
